# How to initialize a property in a service for a set of components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

My service looks like this:

```
export class UserService {
  constructor() {}

  coords: Coordinates;

  getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.coords = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    });
  }
}
```

I initialize a property `coords`, by calling `getPosition()` method

And I have several components.
All of these components use this property.
So I want to call userService.getPosition(), when I am instantiating any of these components.
But for another components, the variable should stay untouched.

All of these components are a part of my DashboardModule, which imports DashboardRouting.
And the DashboardRouting looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WallComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'places',
    component: PlacesComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'object/:id',
    component: ObjectComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('DashboardRoutingModule');
  }
}
```

If you look carefully, Routing uses thee components:
WallComponent
PlacesComponent
ObjectComponent

All these components (pages) uses UserService.coords property.
So it should be initialized.
So the method should be called in each of the components in ngOnInit() method - but I want to wrap all these components with in a single parent component, which will only initialized the UserService.coords property (will call UserService.getPosition() method).

How should I rework this?

Comment: Can you please clarify your goal ? The `for another components, the variable should stay untouched.` part is confusing to me. Also if you want to share a variable across several components, you might want to use a BehaviorSubject to store it (so you can get updates). On the contrary, if you want to share position retrieving mechanism _but not actual data_ you should only expose a `getPosition()` method and store answer in related components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a service globally, it will be a singleton, so any component or service will access the same instance, so they will *see* each others' changes.
But if you provide a service in a component (see `DashboardWrapperComponent` below), it will create a new instance for that component and its children, regardless of whether there's a globally provided instance or not. In this case, only the child components will see each others' changes.

So this should solve the requirement *for another components, the variable should stay untouched*.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-wrapper',
    template: `
        <div>
            <app-child></app-child>
        </div>
    `,
    provide: [
        FancyService,
    ]
})
export class DashboardWrapperComponent {

}
```

But currently you don't have a common parent to those pages where you want to have the shared service instance.
That can be achieved the following way:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: DashboardWrapperComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: WallComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'places',
        component: PlacesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'object/:id',
        component: ObjectComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-wrapper',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    provide: [
        FancyService,
    ]
})
export class DashboardWrapperComponent {

}
```

I know you had `''` as the root route, I am not sure if you can have `''` on 2 levels of the routes, eg. both for `DashboardWrapperComponent` and `WallComponent`, so I added `'home'` there.

Comment: it is because that there must be no page like /home, there are only 3 pages. wall, places, object/{id}. So wrapper should be for all of these. Yes, service is global, but, the method of the service should be called only in the wrapper, the wrapper itself must not have any route/page. It must only call service method and display a component, depending on the current route.

Comment: Type '{ path: string; component: typeof DashboardComponent; children: ({ path: string; component: typeof WallComponent; } | { path: string; component: typeof PlacesComponent; } | { ...; } | { ...; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Routes'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'path' does not exist in type 'Routes'.

Comment: I rewrote Routing following:

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'wall',
        component: WallComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'places',
        component: PlacesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'object/:id',
        component: ObjectComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'wall',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

Comment: but it is not loading the DashboardComponent for some reason

Comment: Is the `DashboardComponent` listed in the `declarations` in the module where it is used?

Comment: Yes. All is ok now. for me it should be path: ''

Answer (score 0):

logically everytime the `getPosition()` method is called, the `coords` property will be updated, if you want to set it only once, you can initialize it to null, then set it once when the `getPosition()` called for the first time, i.e:

```js
export class UserService {
  coords: Coordinates | null = null;

  getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      if (this.coords === null) {
          this.coords = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

hope this helps getting you on the right way :-)

Comment: this is a bit another thing. I know that I can update the value etc. It is not that I need:) but anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am wondering of something like having a DashboardComponent, which will call the `UserService.gePosition()` method in its own `ngOnInit()` method, andi t will have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` thing as a template, to load the `WallComponent`, `PlacesComponent` or `ObjectComponent` components

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, by creating `DashboardComponent` with template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

and changed the routing in the next way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'wall',
        component: WallComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'places',
        component: PlacesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'object/:id',
        component: ObjectComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'wall',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```